# transfer data to a servlet from a jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I have an input in my jsf page like this

```
<html:inputText id="ResponseOK" value="#{bean.ResponseOK}" binding="#{bean.ResponseOKInput}" />
```

I want to get the value in a servlet (by request.getParameter ("ResponseOK")) when i click on a command button

```
<html:commandButton value="Valider" action="#{bean.callServlet}"/>
```

which call a function

```
public void callServlet()
    {
         String url = "http://localhost:8080/TestOne/Timers";  //servlet
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
            try {  

               context.getExternalContext().redirect(url);  

            }catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            finally{  
               context.responseComplete();  
            }  
    }
```

Unfortunately, in my servlet the variable Ok , return only null

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String Ok = request.getParameter("ResponseOK");// return null
        System.out.println(timerOk);
        }
```

thank you very much

Comment: instead of redirect , shouldn't you do a rd.forward(request,response) ;

Comment: @Satya thank you for your help , but requestDispatcher allow to get data from another servlet , and here i need to get data from my jsf page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to be able to get a property from the request, the input must have the name attribute:

```
<html:inputText id="ResponseOK" value="#{bean.ResponseOK}" binding="#{bean.ResponseOKInput}"  name="ResponseOK"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not too familiar with the JSF framework but i think your problem is the action button.

This button is not a submit button so the value of the input is not being sent to the request.

When calling a GET request, you need to pass the parameter in URL itself, so you need the url to look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestOne/Timers?ResponseOK=value
```

So you need to transfer the value of the ResponseOK input to the `callServlet` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help , but the name attribute doesn t exist for a jsf input text , only for jsp. So i can ' t retrieve the property >_<

Comment: look at the generated html, does it have a name attribute?

Comment: Thank you very much . Indeed , in the generated html , a name field appear:index:ResponseOK, then i change the get request by a post request and it works great now. You save me , thank you :p